# What does extend for a configuration do?

Tags: sbt

In SBT I create a new config, called `katebush`, as follows:

```
lazy val KateBush: Configuration = config("katebush")
```

When I try to run `katebush:compile` I get an error. That's what I expect.

```
> katebush:compile
[error] No such setting/task
[error] katebush:compile
[error]                 ^
```

Now I extend `Compile` in my config definition, and I expect to pick up the compile from the inherited scope.

```
lazy val KateBush: Configuration = config("katebush") extend Compile
```

Except it doesn't work:

```
> katebush:compile
[error] No such setting/task
[error] katebush:compile
[error]                 ^
```

But if I add in the defaults to the config (in `build.sbt`) so it looks as follows:

```
lazy val KateBush: Configuration = config("katebush") extend Compile

inConfig(KateBush)(Defaults.compileSettings)
```

it works fine:

```
> katebush:compile
[info] Updating {file:/Users/jacek/sandbox/so-25596360/}so-25596360...
[info] Resolving org.fusesource.jansi#jansi;1.4 ...
[info] Done updating.
[success] Total time: 0 s, completed Aug 31, 2014 11:35:47 PM
```

So, my question is, what exactly does `extend` for a configuration do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**DISCLAIMER** I've got a rather basic understanding of the `config` concept of sbt.

**tl;dr** Extending a configuration is solely to inherit the dependencies groups not settings.

From the sources of [final case class Configuration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L58):

```
def extend(configs: Configuration*) = Configuration(name, description, isPublic, configs.toList ::: extendsConfigs, transitive)
```

By default, `extendsConfigs` is `Nil` as can be seen in the [sbt.Configurations](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L7) object:

```
def config(name: String) = new Configuration(name)
```

[that resolves to](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L56) (note `Nil`)

```
def this(name: String) = this(name, "", true, Nil, true)
```

In [sbt.IvySbt.toIvyConfiguration](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Ivy.scala#L585):

```
import org.apache.ivy.core.module.descriptor.{ Configuration => IvyConfig }
```

and that's where the support of the `config` concept ends in sbt and Ivy steps in. That's where you'd have to look at the documentation of Ivy.

But before that read [Advanced configurations example](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Advanced-Configurations-Example.html) where it says:

> This is an example .scala build definition that demonstrates using *Ivy
>   configurations to group dependencies*.

That's the beginning of the explanation. Ivy configurations are to group dependencies and `extend`ing a configuration is to extend the grouping.

From [the official documentation of Ivy about the conf element](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/ivyfile/conf.html):

> a configuration is a way to use or construct a module.(...)
>   a module may need some other modules and artifacts only at build time, and some others at runtime. All those differents ways to use or build a module are called in Ivy module configurations.

Reading along you can find the answer to your question (that I'm myself yet to digest, too):

> A configuration can also extend one or several other ones of the same
>   module. When a configuration extends another one, then all artifacts
>   required in the extended configuration will also be required in the
>   configuration that extends the other one. For instance, if
>   configuration B extends configuration A, and if artifacts art1 and
>   art2 are required in configuration A, then they will be automatically
>   required in configuration B. On the other hand, artifacts required in
>   configuration B are not necessarily required in configuration A.
>
> This notion is very helpful to define configurations which are similar
>   with some differences.

At the bottom of the page, there's the *Examples* section with an example with `runtime` config that has *"runtime will be composed of all dependencies, all transitively, including the dependencies declared only in compile."*

With this, you can now understand the `config` concept in sbt as a dependencies groups and what's grouped in `Compile` is available in `Runtime` as [its definition looks as follows](https://github.com/sbt/sbt/blob/0.13/ivy/src/main/scala/sbt/Configuration.scala#L36):

```
lazy val Runtime = config("runtime") extend (Compile)
```

Comment: Fantastic reply thanks. Rather disappointed that's all extend does.

Comment: What else would you expect? Settings are sbt while configurations come from Ivy. Perhaps sbt would have done more, but they're different concepts - configurations (Ivy/dependencies) vs scopes (sbt/namespaces).

Comment: I would have expected a config to inherit tasks/settings from parent configs. This is SBT - I don't care what Ivy does under the hood, nor should I.

Comment: I can understand the stand. I'm more to follow the rules of sbt at the moment until I've finally grasped all the concepts thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had to figure this out, so I thought this was worth clarifying.  The configuration has to be added to the project for delegation to the extended configuration to occur:

```
lazy val KateBush: Configuration = config("katebush") extend Compile

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).configs(KateBush)
```

will work fine.  If you

```
inspect katebush:compile
```

then you can view the delegation chain:

```
...
[info] Delegates:
[info]  katebush:compile
[info]  compile:compile
[info]  *:compile
[info]  {.}/katebush:compile
[info]  {.}/compile:compile
[info]  {.}/*:compile
[info]  */katebush:compile
[info]  */compile:compile
[info]  */*:compile
...
```